# TinyMCE link plugin add custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have TinyMCE v 3.5.11. In link plugin I have add custom

```
<tr>
                        <td><label for="class_list">{#param}</label></td>
                        <td><input id="parameter" name="parameter" type="text" value="" style="width: 200px" /></td>
                    </tr>
```

in js

```
if (e = ed.dom.getParent(ed.selection.getNode(), 'A')) {
            f.href.value = ed.dom.getAttrib(e, 'href');
            f.linktitle.value = ed.dom.getAttrib(e, 'title');
            f.parameter.value = ed.dom.getAttrib(e, 'parameter');
            f.insert.value = ed.getLang('update');
            selectByValue(f, 'link_list', f.href.value);
            selectByValue(f, 'target_list', ed.dom.getAttrib(e, 'target'));
            selectByValue(f, 'class_list', ed.dom.getAttrib(e, 'class'));
        }


tinymce.each(ed.dom.select("a"), function(n) {
                if (ed.dom.getAttrib(n, 'href') == '#mce_temp_url#') {
                    e = n;
                    alert(f.parameter.value);
                    ed.dom.setAttribs(e, {
                        href : href,
                        title : f.linktitle.value,
                        parameter: f.parameter.value,
                        target : f.target_list ? getSelectValue(f, "target_list") : null,
                        'class' : f.class_list ? getSelectValue(f, "class_list") : null
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            ed.dom.setAttribs(e, {
                href : href,
                title: f.linktitle.value,
                parameter: f.parameter.value
            });
```

When I look in source plugin I don't see this parameter. But if I firebug looking html I see this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted a [pull request: #4515](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/pull/4515) to the official repo.

Usage

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '.tinymce',
  plugins: 'link',
  toolbar: 'link',
  link_data_list: [
    { title: 'Custom 1', slug: 'custom_1' },
    { title: 'Custom 2', slug: 'custom_2' },
  ]
});
```

It will generate

```
<a ... data-custom_1="your data 1" data-custom_2="your data 2">Your favourite link</a>
```